# why controller as syntax not working in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-grid

I am using new **controller as** syntax to remove $**scope**  .But I am facing one problem while using **ui.grid**  here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/ye0HXTbKv6dDYTQ0DMyX?p=preview

I am using this ui grid 
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro

when I used like that

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged(self, function(row) {
      var msg = 'row selected ' + row.entity.age;
      console.log(row);
    });
```

when I use like that used **self** instead of $scope .it not worked it give me error .when I click any row it don't give me console output.

But when I used like that it works properly why ?

```
gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function(row) {
          var msg = 'row selected ' + row.entity.age;
          console.log(row);
        });
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/1525

Comment: every thing is working file only click event not fire why ?

Comment: did you check the url that i provided earlier ?

Comment: yes ..but that was previous version of ng-grid ..I am using new version of ng-grid

Comment: Pass ``null`` instead of ``$scope`` to avoid errors.  It seems other than ``$scope`` and ``null`` nothing else is expected by the function. Inside function , declare ``var self = this`` to make use ``self`` instead of ``scope``.